# Limit access to the database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

how do I limit the user access to the database I installed to the management studio for only certain people(probably me alone) to access?

But I got a surprise when I saw the database I installed to my client pc was able to be opened using window authentication. I thought it is only able to be opened by the new user I created for that database.

so how do I remove the database from being viewed by those login using window authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL management studio go to "**Security**". Its quite possible that you will find some Windows accounts in there. This is normal behavior and they are put there on installment of the SQL instance.

What you can do is delete the ones you don't want poking around in the DB. **Make sure** that you at least keep **1 db administrator**.

You can also **restrict** their access to read_only. Read [this article](http://community.ingres.com/wiki/Ingres_Enterprise_Access_MSSQL_Quick_Start) on creating/editing users. Goto the properties of the user you want to edit and goto "**Manage Server Roles**". Learn more about [server roles here](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Roles.htm)

Comment: if i do this, this will make the management studio only used by me alone. If there happen on other people want to install new software using mssql, it would not be possible for him.  I would think of whether i can remove the users under my specific database?  Currently under that specific database, i can see my name, dbo, guest, Information_schema, sys. I tried to remove all except my name.. but i failed to delete any of them.